# Bottom margin Android LinearLayout item in XML ignored, but works in Java code

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, margins

I am developing an app with an activity with member reactions on a hike event. The reactions are the yellow "balloons" which are made using a LinearLayout. Each item is constructed from a XML file (listitem_deelnemerreactie.xml) which defines the layout for a reaction item. The top level of this layout file is a LinearLayout my itself.

I want some spacing between the separate elements, as well as some right margin. The most straightforward way to so this should be: setting a bottom and right margin on the top-level LinearLAyout element of the listitem_deelnemerreactie.xml  layout file.

But setting the bottom margin on the LinearLayout has no effect on the vertical spacing, though the right margin does have an effect.

The only way to be able to set a vertical margin appears to be: setting is in the Java code, after attaching the inflated view to the container.
See the two images for the effect and the code. 
Though setting the margins in the code is a working workaround, I still think it is strange this cannot be achieved in the XML. Why is the bottom margin attribute ignored while the right margin is not?

Any ideas?

[image: Margins set in XML layout file]

[image: Margins set in Java code]

Comment: have you ever solved this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set an android:padding="10dp" for example on your elements to spaced them ?

Comment: Padding works on the internal of an item and does not set outer spacing. The padding is set in the drawable which I use as a background to add some space between the text and the border. It is not meant to set spacing between the separate elements.